# Unable to see increased Hard disk in Linux VMware® Workstation 9.0.2

Tags: vmware-workstation

I increased hard disk space from 40 GB to 110 GB in VMware® Workstation 9.0.2, but I am unable to see the increased hard disk space in Linux VMware.

Comment: How do you check the change in guest OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After you have increased the disk size from Workstation client,
2. Start the VM. Install `system-config-lvm` (`yum install` or `sudo apt-get install`)
3. Run `fdisk /dev/sda`  to create partition.
4. Initialize the partition from `system-config-lvm` .

For details and more info visit [How to expand disk capacity for vmware linux virtual machine](http://ireasoning.com/articles/linux_vmware_resize_disk.php)

Comment: Steps are very clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome ! Let me know if you wanna know how to extend windows volume.